# TinyMCE removes blank elements

Tags: tinymce

I have an element on my page which has no content. e.g

```
<p> &nbsp; </p>
```

When I try to edit this element in TinyMCE, it removes the element completely. I want this functionality and give users an option to edit this tag using tinyMCE but I am unable to figure out how.

Thanks

Comment: I fixed it by commenting the following lines

//   if (s.padd_empty_editor) {
//    t.onPostProcess.add(function(ed, o) {
//     o.content = o.content.replace(/^(<p[^>]*>(&nbsp;|&#160;|\s|\u00a0|)<\/p>[\r\n]*|<br \/>[\r\n]*)$/, '');
//    });
//   }

Comment: where did you remove the lines?